# VS2015 BootstrapAsync returned false

Tags: windows, windows-10-v1607, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone

I am trying to create an app on my PC for windows phone(mobile) 10 and my phone is not getting loaded by my Visual Studio Installation. It used to work a week or two before and all of a sudden it stopped working. Now when ever I build an app, i get this error

```
Error       BootstrapAsync returned false.
Error       DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023436
```

I have tried everything stated on superuser and other sites. I have restarted IpOverUSB service to no avail. I have tried turning off developer mode and turning it back on on the phone and the PC.
I do not want to reset my phone as it is my regular use phone with a lot of data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: can anyone help? *bump*

Comment: ask on xda, they have more ideas: http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile

Comment: Ok. I'll try XDA out.